# Does a fighter aircraft slow down when firing machine guns?

Tags: military, aircraft-physics

I imagine the recoil of a powerful machine gun or cannon would decelerate a plane significantly. Is this an issue?

Comment: Short version of the answer: No.

Comment: Significantly?  No.  Compare the mass of the ammunition being fired to the mass of the aircraft.  For a .50 caliber, typical bullets weigh about 40-50 g.  Say the gun fires 20 bullets per second, that's about 1 kg per second.  A typical fighter, say an F-16, weighs something over 9000 kg.  Muzzle velocity would be about 900 m/s, vs a subsonic (jet) speed of 200-300 m/s.